Chainlink CCIP get started example return NotEnoughBalance
I'm testing the Chainlink CCIP Getting Started example on maintnet, I'm getting NotEnoughBalance error, although I've sent LINK to the contract sender address.
Error provided by the contract:
NotEnoughBalance
Parameters:
{
 "currentBalance": {
  "value": "0"
 },
 "calculatedFees": {
  "value": "36745918252344934"
 }
}

You may want to cautiously increase the gas limit if the transaction went out of gas.


Have you changed anything in the Sender or Receiver contract?

Make sure that you're funding your Sender contract with LINK token on the same network at which you've deployed the Sender contract.

It's not mentioned on the Chainlink CCIP Getting Started example, but you must pegSwap chainlink to the right smart contract chainlink address.
Example in polygon : swap to Wlink
https://docs.chain.link/resources/link-token-contracts#polygon
Thnks
